# Java enum type to Json in Vertx

Tags: json, enums, vert.x

This is my model:

```
public class Articulo {
    private String leyenda;
    private tipo_producto tipoProducto;

public Articulo() {
    
}
public Articulo(String leyenda, tipo_producto tipoProducto) {
        this.leyenda = leyenda;
        this.tipoProducto = tipoProducto;
}

public enum tipo_producto {
        ESTANDAR("Estandar"),
        SERVICIO("Servicio"),
        KIT("Kit"),
        MATRIZ("Matriz");
        
        private final String tproducto;
        
        private tipo_producto(String tproducto) {
            this.tproducto = tproducto;
        }

        public String getTproducto() {
            return tproducto;
        }
}
```

This is my "business Articulo":

```
public void getAll(RoutingContext routingContext) {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        pgClient
        .query(SELECT_ALL)
        .execute(ar -> {
            if (ar.succeeded()) {
                RowSet<Row> rows = ar.result();
                List<Articulo> articulos = new ArrayList<>();
                
                rows.forEach(row -> {
                   String leyenda = row.getString("leyenda");
                tipo_producto tipoProducto = tipo_producto .valueOf(row.getString("tipo_producto")); <---PROBLEM!!!
                Articulo articulo = new Articulo (leyenda, tipoProducto);
                articulo.setLeyenda(leyenda);
                articulo.setTipoProducto(tipoProducto);
                articulos.add(articulo);
});     
                response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .setStatusCode(200)
                .end(Json.encodePrettily(articulos));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failure: " + ar.cause().getMessage());
                response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
                .end(Json.encodePrettily(ar.cause().getMessage()));
            }
        });
}
```

**Question**
I only expose shortened versions of code (no getters and setters). The "model" part and the part where the problem is.

When I try to test my API, while I have no error, the API stops when it tries to convert the enum type ... and I don't know how to deserialize an enum type in json. TIA for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. My confusion was here:

```
public enum tipo_posicion {
        NORMAL("Normal"),
        CONSIGNACION("Consignacion");

        private final String tposicion;

        private tipo_posicion(String tposicion) {
            this.tposicion = tposicion;
        }

        public String getPosicion() {
            return tposicion;
        }
    }
```

enum is in UPPERCASE with argument in lowercase. The query result

```
row.getString("tipo_producto")
```

**was lowercase**. The solution was as simple as

```
row.getString("tipo_producto").toUpperCase();
```